# Why does this loop keep running?

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm following an online course and I'm certain that my code is exactly the same, but mine keeps running instead of stopping after 10 times. Can anyone see the problem?

```
for (let rep = 1; rep <= 10; rep = rep++) {
  console.log('Lifting weights repetition 1 ️‍♀️');
}
```

Comment: an assignment of a post increment does not change the assigned value. in short, you assign the same value.

Comment: Try this: `for (let rep = 1; rep <= 10; rep++)`

Comment: because `rep` is always equal to 1

Comment: for (let rep = 1; rep <= 10;  rep++) {
  console.log('Lifting weights repetition 1 ️‍♀️');
}
the issue is caused at rep=rep++

Comment: To be precise, the order in which `rep = rep++` is executed is `rep = rep` and then `rep += 1`. The `rep + 1` in turn is never assigned to anything.